# ERROR: an illegal memory access was encountered When I use constant memory

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia

I meet a problem when i used constant memory. It will happen the error:

```
ERROR: an illegal memory access was encountered
```

It seem the kernel function doesn't execute.
But if I don't chose the constant memory, everything are ok. So it makes me so confused. I had thought very long time. But I still don't the reason. Can you help me to solve the problem?  Thank you very much.

If the variable s is not used constant memory, everything are ok. But if the s is used constant memory, the program will break.

the variable that used constant memory define as followed:

```
#ifdef USE_CONST_MEM
__constant__ Sphere s[SPHERES];
#else
Sphere          *s;
#endif
```

the kernel function defined as followed:

```
#ifdef USE_CONST_MEM
__global__ void kernel(unsigned char *ptr) {
    printf("ok2");
#else
__global__ void kernel(Sphere *s, unsigned char *ptr) {
#endif
    // map from threadIdx/BlockIdx to pixel position
    printf("ok2");
    int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    int offset = x + y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    REAL   ox = (x - DIM / 2);
    REAL   oy = (y - DIM / 2);

    REAL   r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
    REAL   maxz = -INF;
    __syncthreads();
    for (int i = 0; i<SPHERES; i++) {
        REAL   n;
        REAL   t = s[i].hit(ox, oy, &n);
        if (t > maxz) {
            REAL fscale = n;
            r = s[i].r * fscale;
            g = s[i].g * fscale;
            b = s[i].b * fscale;
            maxz = t;
            printf("r: %.2f g: %.2f, b %.2f\n", r, g, b);
        }
    }
    __syncthreads();
    ptr[offset * 4 + 0] = (int)(r * 255);
    ptr[offset * 4 + 1] = (int)(g * 255);
    ptr[offset * 4 + 2] = (int)(b * 255);
    ptr[offset * 4 + 3] = 255;
}

// globals needed by the update routine
struct DataBlock {
    unsigned char   *dev_bitmap;
    CPUAnimBitmap  *bitmap;
};
```

there is the function that call the kernel function.

```
void generate_frame(DataBlock *d, int ticks) {
    //START_GPU

    //movin the spheres
    kernelMoving << <128, 32 >> >(s, SPHERES);
    printf("ok0\n");
    // generate a bitmap from our sphere data
    dim3    grids(DIM / 16, DIM / 16);
    dim3    threads(16, 16);

#ifdef USE_CONST_MEM
    Sphere *d_s;
    cudaGetSymbolAddress((void **)&d_s, s);
    printf("ok0-1\n");
    kernel << <grids, threads >> >(s, d->dev_bitmap);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaError_t error = cudaGetLastError();
    if(error!=cudaSuccess)
    {
       fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(error) );
       exit(-1);
    }
    printf("ok0-1-1\n");
#else
    printf("ok0-2\n");
    kernel << <grids, threads >> >(s, d->dev_bitmap);
#endif
    printf("ok1\n");
    //END_GPU

    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(d->bitmap->get_ptr(),
        d->dev_bitmap,
        d->bitmap->image_size(),
        cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
}
```

the initialzation code as followed:

```
#ifdef USE_CONST_MEM
#else
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void**)&s,
        sizeof(Sphere) * SPHERES));
#endif

    // allocate temp memory, initialize it, copy to constant
    // memory on the GPU, then free our temp memory
    Sphere *temp_s = (Sphere*)malloc(sizeof(Sphere) * SPHERES);
    for (int i = 0; i<SPHERES; i++) {
        temp_s[i].r = rnd(1.0f);
        temp_s[i].g = rnd(1.0f);
        temp_s[i].b = rnd(1.0f);
        temp_s[i].x = rnd(1000.0f) - 500;
        temp_s[i].y = rnd(1000.0f) - 500;
        temp_s[i].z = rnd(1000.0f) - 500;
        temp_s[i].radius = rnd(10.0f) + 5;

        temp_s[i].dx = STEP_SIZE * ((rand() / (float)RAND_MAX) * 2 - 1);
        temp_s[i].dy = STEP_SIZE * ((rand() / (float)RAND_MAX) * 2 - 1);
        temp_s[i].dz = STEP_SIZE * ((rand() / (float)RAND_MAX) * 2 - 1);
    }

#ifdef USE_CONST_MEM
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(s, temp_s,
        sizeof(Sphere) * SPHERES));
#else
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(s, temp_s, sizeof(Sphere)*SPHERES, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
#endif

    free(temp_s);
```

the version of cuda is 8.0. the system is ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I don't see any constant memory anywhere in the code you have shown. Without an [MCVE] I fail to see how someone could provide an answer based only on the code you have shown. Please edit your question to include one.

Comment: thanks for reply. It's my fault that forget copy the constant code. I have update my question. I also provide the url that can see my full code.

Comment: Actually you are supposed to provide the [mcve] in the question itself, not in an external link.  See item 1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: thanks, I have updated my question, there are four parts. The part of  defining constant variable, the part of kernel function, the part of calling kernel function, the part of initialzation code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I know where I am wrong. When I used constant memory, I also try to change it's value in the function kernel_moving that try to modify the constant value. So the program will break. Now, I change to this, it works.

```
    #ifdef USE_CONST_MEM
    //printf("the number of SPHERES is %d\n", SPHERES);
    Sphere *temp_s = (Sphere*)malloc(sizeof(Sphere) * SPHERES);
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(temp_s, s, sizeof(Sphere) * SPHERES,0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    Sphere* dev_temp_s;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_temp_s, sizeof(Sphere) * SPHERES);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_temp_s, temp_s, sizeof(Sphere) * SPHERES, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    kernelMoving << <128, 32 >> >(dev_temp_s, SPHERES);
    cudaMemcpy(temp_s, dev_temp_s, sizeof(Sphere) * SPHERES, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(s, temp_s, sizeof(Sphere) * SPHERES));
    free(temp_s);
    cudaFree(dev_temp_s);
    #else
    kernelMoving << <128, 32 >> >(s, SPHERES);
    #endif
```